# Take the magnitude of a real polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

**Question:**

Let $ \mathbb{R_2[x]} $ denote the inner product space of polynomials over $ \mathbb{R} $ having degree at most two, with inner product given by
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int^{1}_{0} f(x)g(x)dx, $$ for every $$ f, g \in \mathbb{R_2[x]} $$ Apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure to the standard basis $ \{1, x, x^2\} $ for $ \mathbb{R_2[x]} $ in order to produce an orthonormal basis for $ \mathbb{R_2[x]} $.

**My Steps:**

$$ e_{1} = \frac{1}{||1||} = 1 $$

$$ e_{2} = \frac{x - \int^{1}_{0} x \cdot 1 \cdot dx}{||x - \int^{1}_{0} x \cdot 1 \cdot dx||} = \frac{x - \frac{1}{2}}{?}$$

I'm not sure how to take the magnitude of the polynomial to continue solving for the orthonormal basis.

Comment: As Carl points out on his answer the inner product induces a norm. The norm for an element is the root of the inner product with itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$||f(x)||=\sqrt{\langle f, f\rangle}.$$

This is how it is defined.